# Out of memory on 50MB file serialize and save

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine, out-of-memory, filestream

I have a 200MB object array created in memory which is causing out of memory problems when saving this array to file using this method. I broke the array apart into sections (around 50MB per section), however, it is still causing memory issues when saving.

File Manager Class:

```
public void WriteStream(string saveLocation, object o)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(saveLocation, FileMode.Create);
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(fs, o);
    fs.Close();
}
```

From another class:

```
    FileManager fm = new FileManager();
    for(int i = 0; i < tileData.Length; i++)
    {
        string path = appDataFolder + @"\"+levelName+"layer"+i.ToString()+".dat";
        fm.WriteStream(path, tileData[i]);
    }
```

Serializable object that is being saved (tileData above):

```
[Serializable]
public class TileMapData : ISerializable
{
    public int layer;
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public int[,] type;
    public int[,] bitmask;
    public int[,] status;
    public int[,] groupID;
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    { 
      //omitted to save space
    }

    public TileMapData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    { 
       //omitted to save space
    }
}
```

What would be a way to overcome this problem?

Second attempt using StreamWriter this time, still same problem.

```
     public void BinaryWriteSave(string saveLocation, object o)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = ObjectToByteArray(o);
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(saveLocation, FileMode.Create)))
        {
            bw.Write(byteArray);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: It shouldn't. What was the memory consumption of your process at the time of Exception?

Comment: 200Mb is a lot... Are you sure your app is running as x64?

Comment: BinaryWriter jumps to mind as the better alternative here.  When you are dancing around OOM then it gets time to start thinking about letting your program run in 64-bit mode.

Comment: @DanPantry A `FileStream` object doesn't persist the entire file in memory for reading (that's the point of a stream) and it only buffers some portion of its output for writing, not everything that has been written.

Comment: can we see the object(structure) you are trying to serialize? I have the feeling that maybe you have some kind of recursive dependencies in there ;)

Comment: Updated and added exception + object I am trying to serialize. I tried StreamWriter same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a memory mapped filed for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but too long for a comment.

That exception indicates that your 3rd party library, which I assume is unity3d from the icon image, actually ran out of memory, being unable to allocate 864 Megabytes.  That's not a .Net exception; .Net and the BinaryFormatter never threw an out-of-memory exception and the FileStream buffers never got too large.

So, a few ideas:

1. Find out the exact traceback where the unmanaged exception is thrown.  You can do that by breaking in Visual Studio when all exceptions are thrown via "Debug" -> "Exceptions" and checking "Thrown" in the "Exceptions" dialog: 
   [image]
   Then enable unmanaged debugging as is described here: [How to: Enable Debugging of Unmanaged Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tdw0c6sf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  (You may only need to [enable breaking on `SEHException` when thrown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712787%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).)  Once you know the object type(s) and traceback that are causing the memory use, you can update your question with that information and search for existing answers.
2. When serializing to binary, unity3d would seem to be allocating proxy data structures to serialize that are much larger than its normal data structures.  The traceback from the above may give you an idea which it is.  Is there any reason it would need to do so?  For instance, are you converting a sparse matrix representation to a non-sparse matrix representation for serialization?  If so, try not to do that.
3. If unity3d really needs to allocate that much memory, consider breaking your data down into small chunks and storing each small chunk into the file separately.  This article has instructions how: [Serializing lots of different objects into a single file](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2007/07/serializing-lots-of-different-objects.html)
4. Alternatively, perhaps your database is corrupt somehow, perhaps containing circular references when this is not allowed by unity3d.  What you can do is to try to identity the bad data by the method of bisections: try to serialize one half of the data, and then the second.  If only one fails, then the corruption is likely in that half.  Repeat until you have found the corrupt object.